# Inno Setup - verysilent yet still have to click next

Tags: inno-setup

So I cant get this to work as intended. I have 4 small programmes that need to be installed silently. However using the verysilent tag, each of the 4 programmes pops up asking me to click next a couple of times as they would normally.

Not sure how to auto click next or why silentinstall isnt working (probably not supported by my programmes?)

Any thing I can do?

Comment: It is possible to do something with the NextButtonClick? I'm not sure how to do this code and cant find any examples.

Comment: Did you implement those installer yourself? Or are you running existing installers? What are you exactly doing/trying? What do you mean by *"verysilent **tag**"*?

Comment: They're exsisting installers. In my company I often have to send 4 applications to new starters. So I'm trying to put it all in INNO to do for me. I read online verysilent tag meant it would install in the background rather than prompts. So now, I'm trying to work out how to do it. Auto click next or some other way.

Comment: Are the existing installers built with Inno Setup?

Comment: No they are not.

Comment: The `/verysilent` switch is a feature of Inno Setup that allows you to run installers built with Inno Setup silently. It does not (and cannot) magically run random sub-installer silently. And we can hardly help you running those installers silently, if we do not know anything about them. Let only, if they even support silent installation. And this is not a programming question at all anyway.

Comment: Ok Ok. Wasn't trying to annoy anyone. Was trying to come up with a solution a problem. Googled and came across Silent Install Builder, which does just that but costs $200. Then saw Inno setup. Mostly does what I want it to do but not sure how to simulate keystrokes etc. Was only seeing if there was any tips :/

Comment: Most installers do support silent installation. But we cannot help you, without knowing what installers are we talking about here. Try running them with `/?` switch to see, if they offer any help => There's no magic solution. You have to tell us more. Otherwise your question is pointless. Simulating keystrokes is really bad solution.

Comment: Its our own software that was made for us. /? didnt do anything for me. I dont think they support the /silent switch/tag hence I was wondering if there was another way. Why is simulating keystrokes bad?

Comment: What if installation goes unexpected way for any reason (some error)? If you keep sending keystrokes, you get unpredictable results -> Did you consider reimplementing the installers yourself? Do they do anything fancy? Or do they just deploy some files?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement the "/Verysilent" Flag.
As it means it will be executed as a parameter.
You need to identify which types of installers are you using and what parameters that they support..